#  Add multiple Checkbutton and store the result in a list

Tags: python, list, tkinter

I want to add several Checkbutton in my Tkinter app. I don't know the number of Checkbutton I insert when I launch the program (depend on a DB call).

I wrote this code:

```
for row in information:
    self.__checkBoxValue.append(StringVar())
    Checkbutton(self.__frame2, variable=self.__checkBoxValue[-1], onvalue="%s*%s" % (row[0], row[1])).grid(row=TDMUsed[row[0]], column=DateUsed[row[2]])
```

When I run the code, all the checkbox are grayed and checked. But, If I delete the variable option, the checkbox is ok.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try setting the value of the `StringVar` instance to either your `onvalue` or `offvalue`.

Comment: That's it! I add this after the creation of my StringVar:
    `self.__checkBoxValue[-1].set("OFF")`.
And I initialise my `offvalue` like this: `offvalue="OFF"`